# LongPressGestureRecognizer in watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to do some action when I long press the button in watchkit.
How can I use long press gesture in Watchkit for `WKInterfaceButton`?

Answer (score 3):

So far WatchKit doesn't have gesture recognizers. The only way you can use the force touch (the long press in the watch) is using a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Apple introduced long press gesture recognizers in watchOS3, have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wklongpressgesturerecognizer).